# Waiting for repaint in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to run some code after I change the background of an element. I'd like to run the code after the background is changed **visually**, not just internally. Thus I'd like to wait for a repaint. I tried doing this using rAF, but that does not seem to be the correct way, because the code gets executed before the background color is changed visually (talking about milliseconds though).

I tried to achieve my goal with the following code (without luck):

```
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor =
      "rgb(0, 75, 75)";
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        socket.emit("notify-black");
      });
  });
```

What would be the correct way of waiting for the repaint?

Answer (score 6):

`requestAnimationFrame` will run its callback *just before* the next repaint. Put the code you want to run in a `setTimeout` inside that, since the timeout callback will run almost immediately after the repaint finishes.

You can also use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 75, 75)";
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      socket.emit("notify-black");
    });
  });
});
```

Live demo, using `alert` (which blocks) instead of `socket.emit`:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 75, 75)";
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("notify-black");
    });
  });
});
```

Another example code that takes a screenshot using html2canvas. Open up [example.com](https://example.com/), open your console, and run the following:

```
const script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
script.src = 'https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js'
script.onload = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 75, 75)";
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("body")).then(canvas => {
          document.write('<img src="'+canvas.toDataURL("image/png")+'"/>');
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The emit goes to the server and forwards it to another client which runs a function on retrieval. Sending and receiving this emit goes faster than actually changing the background color locally for some reason. Right now, I just set a timeout for 500ms, but I'd like to remove that guessing factor.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem - see the snippet which uses `alert` to block. At the time the timeout callback runs, the background should have always repainted (`requestAnimationFrame` always runs just before a repaint, a `setTimeout` callback will necessarily run after)

Comment: Yet, the receiving side of the emit never starts its method randomly on its own. It only runs its method after receiving the emit as I've debugged. I am uncertain about why though. I double checked and the emit only arrives once, thus there is no other client trying to communicate.

Comment: From what are you concluding that the color hasn't visually changed when the emit goes off? Do you have color-detection code that you're running or something? (though the DOM *should* be giving the color set by JS even before a repaint)

Comment: Indeed, I have color detection running. When the emit gets received, a picture is taken. From this I know that the background did not yet update visually.

Comment: Using a 150ms timeout, it seems to be working. But that might be dependent on the connection of course. Also, this should rule out that it has to do with the display not refreshing fast enough because if every frame took 150ms to appear, I'd have an fps of a little under 7. This should not be the case on this device.

Comment: I added another example, it still works just fine for me - the `alert` indeed shows with the background already painted, and so does html2canvas. I think your problem is elsewhere, the code in the question seems to be working as desired

Answer (score 1):

The best reliable and working answer including explanation i found, recommend reading this https://www.webperf.tips/tip/measuring-paint-time/

And for reference in case the link isn't available anymore at some point:

```
/**
 * Runs `callback` shortly after the next browser Frame is produced.
 */
function runAfterFramePaint(callback) {
    // Queue a "before Render Steps" callback via requestAnimationFrame.
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const messageChannel = new MessageChannel();

        // Setup the callback to run in a Task
        messageChannel.port1.onmessage = callback;

        // Queue the Task on the Task Queue
        messageChannel.port2.postMessage(undefined);
    });
}
```

Use the following way:

```
elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
runAfterFramePaint(() => {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
```